# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10 in pandas align.py, prob from `query`-- cause/solution?

Tags: python, pandas

Getting the following error, and don't know what it means / how to avoid / whether I should worry:

```
C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py:98: 
  ordm = np.log10(abs(reindexer_size - term_axis_size))
```

while running `query()`.

dtypes:

```
CGI            int64
SITEID         int32
LONGITUDE    float64
LATITUDE     float32
dtype: object
```

Query:

```
towerData = towerData.query('CGI != 0')
```

Pandas 0.16.2

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see a full example.  Just change `towerData.query("CGI != 0")` to `towerData = towerData[towerData.CGI != 0]` and see if it helps.

Comment: That does resolve the problem. Is this  a bug in `query` / should I report?

Comment: I'd slap a debug on it and step through.  If you find the exact line that it fails on, and you can reproduce the bug, then yes you can file a bug with pandas on github.  You'll need to be very specific though.

Comment: i also had same error even in latest pandas 0.18 should report as bug