# Pandas query causing RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I saw a similar post ([RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10 in pandas align.py, prob from `query`-- cause/solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659279/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log10-in-pandas-align-py-prob-fro)), but there was no sample code, followup or answer.  Is this a known bug with `query`?

When using `pd.query()`, I'm getting a `RuntimeWarning` that doesn't make sense to me.  I tried it a few different ways and tried to simplify the data to make sure it wasn't me, but I continually get the warning no matter what I do.  Is anyone able to run the below code without getting the warning?  Is this a bug?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 
                              ('B', [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]), 
                              ('C', list(np.random.randn(5)))])
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace = True)
df.query('15 <= B <= 17')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py:98: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
ordm = np.log10(abs(reindexer_size - term_axis_size))
Out[1]: 
             C
A B 
2 15 -0.852411
3 16 -0.665470
4 17  0.132162
```

I thought maybe it was the fact that I was using `15 <= B <= 17` so I tried to break that down into pieces, but got the same RuntimeWarning.

```
In [2]: df.query('B <= 17')
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py:98: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
ordm = np.log10(abs(reindexer_size - term_axis_size))
Out[2]: 
             C
A B
1 14  0.380167
2 15 -0.852411
3 16 -0.665470
4 17  0.132162

In [3]: df.query('B >= 15')
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py:98: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
ordm = np.log10(abs(reindexer_size - term_axis_size))
Out[3]: 
             C
A B
2 15 -0.852411
3 16 -0.665470
4 17  0.132162
5 18  0.697867
```

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Spyder 3.0.0.dev0
- Python 3.5.2
- Pandas 0.18.1
- Numpy 1.11.1

Comment: What is `reindexer_size` and `term_axis-size`? Is that part of the RuntimeWarning?

Comment: @Alexander That's part of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13135) and it's still open.

It's working properly for me:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
             C
A B
1 14  0.159137
2 15  2.275652
3 16  0.798102
4 17  0.774097
5 18  2.361938

In [3]: df.query('15 <= B <= 17')
Out[3]:
             C
A B
2 15  2.275652
3 16  0.798102
4 17  0.774097

In [4]: df.query('B <= 17')
Out[4]:
             C
A B
1 14  0.159137
2 15  2.275652
3 16  0.798102
4 17  0.774097
```

Comment: Any explanation as to why it is working for you and not for the OP? Curious bc I have a similar situations where it's working fine locally but in test CI tool it's failing (but same version of Python, Pandas being used in both locations).